# A little confused about the modifiers of Java

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

I'm learning Java language. A little confused about the modifier.

Sometimes I saw method inside a class with no modifier, like this for example:

```
public class example0{       
    void example1(){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Normally there is modifier like `public` or `private` in front of `void` in the method to set visibility.

Why sometimes there`s no modifier in front the method like the example above?

What is that mean compare to the one with `public` or `private`?

Comment: I can't believe people answer such questions.

Comment: You should first refer a good tutorial(books are best in my opinion) before starting to code in a language.

Comment: He finds stackoverflow easier than google :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the method has a `default` access, which means it will be accessible only within the package in which the nesting class is located.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have a `default`modifier and it is accesible for the class and the package. Here is a Table with a description out of this link: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private).

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
public      |  y    |    y    |    y     |   y
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  y    |    y    |    y     |   n
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
no modifier |  y    |    y    |    n     |   n    **also known as package-private**
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
private     |  y    |    n    |    n     |   n

y: accessible
n: not accessible
```

Comment: Why didn't you just give the link to that question in the comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private. It helps others coming here.